# How to get one value from JSON format using JS

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to get only one data type from a JSON file using JS.
the field that I want to get is "name".
the JSON format is:

```
{"countries":
 {"country":[
  {"id":"1","name":"Europe","active":"on","dir":"yes"}, 
  {"id":"2","name":"Africa","active":"on","dir":"yes"},
  {"id":"3","name":"North America","active":"on","dir":"yes"}, 
 ]}
}
```

the require result is:
Europe
Africa
North America

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JSON. Your code represents a [(javascript) Object literal/initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

From that Object you can map the name property of each entry of the nested array from `countries.country`.

```js
const myObj = { "countries":
 {"country":[
  {"id":"1","name":"Europe","active":"on","dir":"yes"}, 
  {"id":"2","name":"Africa","active":"on","dir":"yes"},
  {"id":"3","name":"North America","active":"on","dir":"yes"}, 
 ]}
};

const countryNames = myObj.countries.country.map( c => c.name );

console.log(countryNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let countryNames = data.countries.country.filter(item => item.name !== '')
```

OR

```
const countryNames = []
data.countries.country.forEach(item => {
     countryNames.push(item.name)
})

console.log(countryNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {"countries":
 {"country":[
  {"id":"1","name":"Europe","active":"on","dir":"yes"}, 
  {"id":"2","name":"Africa","active":"on","dir":"yes"},
  {"id":"3","name":"North America","active":"on","dir":"yes"}, 
 ]}
}

console.log(
  data.countries.country.map(country => country.name)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through, using

```
// parse it first
let data = JSON.parse( /* your file */);
let arr = [];
for (country in data.countries) {
    for (name in country) {
        arr.push(name)
    }
}
console.log(name);
// Expected result: ['Europe','Africa','North America']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data= JSON.parse(yourJson);

data.countries.country.forEach((item) => {
   console.log(item.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer saves a step from mine - noted, thanks.

```
let obj = {"countries":
 {"country":[
  {"id":"1","name":"Europe","active":"on","dir":"yes"}, 
  {"id":"2","name":"Africa","active":"on","dir":"yes"},
  {"id":"3","name":"North America","active":"on","dir":"yes"}, 
 ]}
}
let objArray = obj.countries.country;
let names = objArray.map(item => item['name']);
console.log(names);
```

Returns an array of names ['Europe', 'Africa', 'North America']

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map